# Javascript, about infinite looping prompt and stopping that loop

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

I'm new to javascript, so that's my back story :) This code keeps crashing my browser, and it won't let me cancel the prompt if I don't cancel on the first attempt, whether I enter a number or not...Anyway, even the game won't work, which is to just to get to a point where the secret number is the person's guessing number. For cancelling the prompt, I even tried  if(answer===null||answer===false||answer==="null")
break; but it won't work. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
var answer=prompt("Enter a number you want to try");

while(secret_number!==Number(answer))
{
if(name===null||name===false||name==="null")
break;

if(Number(answer)>secret_number)
prompt("This number is too high!");

else if(Number(answer)<secret_number)
prompt("This number is too low!");

else
prompt("You got it!");
}

</script>
```

I have a follow-up question. I took into account what people told me and came up with this:

```
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
var answer=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number you want to try"));

while(secret_number!==answer)
{
if(answer == null || answer == "" ||isNaN(answer))
break;

if(answer>secret_number)
answer=prompt("This number is too high!");

else if(answer<secret_number)
answer=prompt("This number is too low!");

else
alert("You got it!");
}
```

My question is, how come my "You got it!" alert keeps going on infinitely? I know I can make it break there, but I want to know why it keeps doing that. It should have that secret_number===answer and break out of the while loop, so obviously it's not doing that, and I don't get why. Thank you again.

Comment: In `if(name===null||name===false||name==="null")` is `name` not supposed to be `answer`?

Comment: sorry, i meant answer, but yeah I had answer in my original code..

Comment: thanks everyone, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have an endless loop is that you don't change `answer`'s value inside your loop. As a result each time the `while` condition is evaluated `answer`  is still the first number entered into the prompt and the loop runs again. Also it's worth noting that if the user enters nothing `answer` will be set to an empty string (`""`)

working version:

```
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
var answer=prompt("Enter a number you want to try");

while(secret_number!==Number(answer))
{
  if(answer===null || answer = ""){
    break;
  }

  if(Number(answer)>secret_number){
    answer = prompt("This number is too high!");
  }
  else if(Number(answer)<secret_number){
    answer = prompt("This number is too low!");
  }

  else{
    alert("You got it!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've found out why `while` loops can be dangerous.  The best solution here is to limit the amount of guesses the user has and to do that you need a counter that is incremented inside the loop and that can simply be done with a `for` loop.

Also, use curly braces to surround your `if` branches.

Lastly, the best way to convert a string into a number is with `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`. Do the conversion right when you get the string and then you don't have to keep converting it every time you want to use it.

```js
var secret_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
alert("For testing only: The secret number is: " + secret_number);
var answer = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number you want to try"), 10);

const GUESSES = 3;

for(var i = 0; i < GUESSES; ++i){
  if(!isNaN(answer)){
    
    if(answer > secret_number) {
      answer = prompt("Try again...This number is too high! (" + (GUESSES - i - 1) + " guesses left.)");
    } else if(answer < secret_number) {
      answer = prompt("Try again...This number is too low! (" + (GUESSES - i - 1) + " guesses left.)");
    } else {
      alert("You got it!");
      break;
    }
  } else {
    alert("You didn't enter a number!");
    break;
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `prompt` is before the loop. Changing `while` to `do while` can fix it:

```js
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 

do {
  var str = prompt("Enter a number you want to try"),
      answer = Number(str);

  if (!str || isNaN(answer)) {
    alert('Bye');
    break;
  }
  
  if (answer > secret_number) {
    alert("This number is too high!");
  } else if (answer < secret_number) {
    alert("This number is too low!");
  } else {
    alert("You got it!");
  }
  
} while (secret_number !== answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```html
<script>
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 

var answer=prompt("Enter a number you want to try");

while(secret_number!=Number(answer)){

 if(Number(answer)>secret_number){
  answer = prompt("This number is too high!");
 }
 else if(Number(answer)<secret_number){
  answer = prompt("This number is too low!");
 }
}

prompt('correct!');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only different from some of the other answers in trying to retain your intent of giving up when no answer is provided:

```
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
var answer=prompt("Enter a number you want to try");

while(secret_number!==Number(answer)) {
    // "" covers case of clicking OK with nothing entered
  // null covers case of clicking Cancel
    if(answer == null || answer == "") {
        break;
  }

    if(Number(answer)>secret_number) {
        answer = prompt("This number is too high!");
    } else if(Number(answer)<secret_number) {
        answer = prompt("This number is too low!");
    }
}
if (secret_number!==Number(answer)) {
    alert("You gave up :(");
} else {
    alert("You got it!");
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h10qt0nn/1/