# Infinite looping alert box in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, alert, infinite

My question is, how come my "You got it!" alert keeps going on infinitely? I know I can make it break there, but I want to know why it keeps doing that. It should have that secret_number===answer and break out of the while loop, so obviously it's not doing that, and I don't get why. Thank you :)

```
var secret_number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
var answer=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number you want to try"));

while(secret_number!==answer)
{
if(answer == null || answer == "" ||isNaN(answer))
break;

if(answer>secret_number)
answer=prompt("This number is too high!");

else if(answer<secret_number)
answer=prompt("This number is too low!");

else
alert("You got it!");
}
```

Comment: Didn't we already cover why `while` loops can cause infinite loops and show the correct way in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970711/javascript-about-infinite-looping-prompt-and-stopping-that-loop We also covered good coding practices in that post as well, but you don't seem to have taken any of that advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the "answer" again in the while loop, you aren't doing a `parseInt` so the value is now a string, and not equivalent to the secret.

The `>` and `<` are converting both values to numeric before comparison, so both of those checks are skipped if you put the right number in, but the while condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a single rule to end the while loop and show the alert.

To end the while loop your secret number and answer must be the same (===), however to show the alert you answer must not be greater or lesser than secret number.

To fix, parseInt the prompts and I would use the same rule to show the alert and finish the program. or even put the alert outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Either change `while(secret_number!==answer)` to `while(secret_number!=answer)`

or

convert `prompt("This number is too high!")` to int using `parseInt` and then assign it to answer 'answer=parseInt(prompt("This number is too high!"));'

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/cnvm19ha/